# Capitalization Bug in Title Prompt

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The title prompt has a capitalization bug:

[image]

That should be "State the ...", with a capital "S".

Comment: I think @Shog9 says that it's unfortunately not a choice. I'll try to find the citation.

Comment: @200_success [why wouldn't it be?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XFr4S.png)

Comment: Thank God it is not a [Pluralization Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/311398) though it is the problem with the same letter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Time was, every prompt started with a lower-case character. Life was good.

Then people started complaining about specific instances. "We're a site for people studying proper English" they said, "It's important we set a good example", they claimed.

Fine. The title prompt here now starts with an upper-case character.